# Inserting Morse Code into binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am trying to insert the Morse Code into a binary tree but my `Insert()` is acting up. I'm stumped as to why it's failing.

Binary tree class:

```
class BST
{
    private:
            struct Node
            {
                string letter;
                string code;
                Node *left;
                Node *right;
            };
            Node *root;

    public:
            BST()
            {
                root = NULL;
            }
            void Insert(Node *&r, string letter, string code)
            {
                if(r == NULL)
                {
                    r = new Node; 
                    r->letter = letter; 
                    r->code = code;
                    r->left = r->right = NULL; 
                }
            }
            void Insert(string letter, string code)
            {
                Node *r = root;
                if(r != NULL)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++)
                    {
                        if(code[i] == '.') r = r->left;
                        else if(code[i] == '-') r = r->right;
                        else break;
                    }
                    Insert(r, letter, code);
                }
                else Insert(root, letter, code);
            }
};
```

Main:

```
struct alphaTree
{
    string letter;
    string code;
};

alphaTree tree[] = {  
                       {"ROOT", ""},  {"E", "."},    {"T", "-"},    {"I", ".."},   {"A", ".-"},   {"N", "-."},   
                       {"M", "--"},   {"S", "..."},  {"U", "..-"},  {"R", ".-."},  {"W", ".--"},  {"D", "-.."},  
                       {"K", "-.-"},  {"G", "--."},  {"O", "---"},  {"H", "...."}, {"V", "...-"}, {"F", "..-."}, 
                       {"L", ".-.."}, {"P", ".--."}, {"J", ".---"}, {"B", "-..."}, {"X", "-..-"}, {"C", "-.-."}, 
                       {"Y", "-.--"}, {"Z", "--.."}, {"Q", "--.-"}  
                    };

for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
{
    t.Insert(tree[i].letter, tree[i].code);
}
```

The first 3 elements of my `tree[]` array get inserted but the program crashes when trying to insert `"I"`.

Comment: Is there a complete lookup table or only M K L Y ?

Answer (score 3):

When you insert a new node parents left and right are not being updated.

You may think parents are updated because you are passing pointer by reference, but you are passing `r` and not `r->left` or `r->root` which you should.

One possible solution is to use `**r` instead if `*r` in `void Insert(string letter, string code)`

You can change something like: ([Working example here](http://ideone.com/WwqaqJ))

```
    void Insert(string letter, string code)
    {
        Node **r = &root;
        if(*r != NULL)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++)
            {
                assert(*r);
                if(code[i] == '.') r = &((*r)->left);
                else if(code[i] == '-') r = &((*r)->right);
                else break;
            }
            Insert(*r, letter, code);
        }
        else Insert(root, letter, code);
    }
```

Not related to your problem, but as side notes:

1. In `for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++)` you are comparing an
   unsigned (length) with singed int. You should change `i` to
   std::string::size_type.
2. In function `void Insert(string letter, string code)` you should add
   assert(*r) before accessing `*r` children.

Comment: I see what you mean. So how should I change my function to do as such?

Comment: I added snippet of function

Comment: When you write `Node *r = root;` you are making a copy of root pointer in r. Although r and root are different locations in memory (containing same value so), `root->left` is same as `r->left` (same location in memory and value). Now if you update `r`, `root` is **not** update. On the other hand if you use `Node **r = &root`, `*r` and `root` are essentially same and changing `*r` would reflect to root also. So I suggested changing `*r` to `**r`. Although there may be multiple more simple solutions.

Comment: Is it necessary to make it a double pointer? Could it not be done if you do: `Node *r = &root;` ?

Comment: Type of `root` is `Node *`, so the type of `&root` would be `Node **`. Now to save the value of type `Node **`, you need a variable of `Node **`.

Comment: Just to get this clear, `&` means to get the memory address of a variable?

Comment: Exactly, you are right. For analogy if `i` is is int, `&i` goes into `int *` variable. If `root` is `Node *`, `&Node` goes into `Node **` variable. You can read more about pointers from some C book. Knowledge of pointer is very helpful in implementing data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++)
{
    if(code[i] == '.') r = r->left;
    else if(code[i] == '-') r = r->right;
    else break;
}
```

When this loop starts, you make sure `r` is never `NULL`. Howover, as there is only one element in the tree it will immediately become `NULL` for the next iteration when you set it to either `r = r->left` or `r = r->right`, as there is only one node in the tree and both it's `left` and `right` are `NULL`.

You are not checking if `r` becomes `NULL` while looping.

The sooner you get to an element with two or more symbols in the morse code, your application crashes trying to read from `r` when it's a `NULL` pointer.

You probably wants to extend your code to something more like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++)
{
    if (code[i] == '.')
    {
        if (r->left)
            r = r->left;
        else
        {
            // todo: code to bind a new node to r->left
            break;
        }
    }
    else // its always either '.' or '-' so there is no need to double check the symbol here
    {
        if (r->right)
            r = r->right;
        else
        {
            // todo: code to bind a new node to r->right
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you are making sure the loop stops while `r` is still a valid pointer. The last valid pointer in the descending tree.

Of course you still have to write the decision to create the new node to the `left` or `right` side of this node.

Comment: OP is adding codes incrementally so he assumes he gets tree arms until code.length(). But yes it is worth to add an `assert` statement there.

Comment: This is the reason alphabets may seem out of order. But they are carefully ordered in a way so that parent is always present when you try to add a new node.

Comment: I see what went wrong, thanks for clearing it up. I'm somewhat new to programming so this answer was the simpler to understand. @MohitJain 's answer works as well but it's difficult for me to visualize.